# Excel VBA: scanning one sheet and copying data to another

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I need some help with this code below.

I am trying to write a program which will scan a column in sheet 2 and have a conditional
statement where if an "x" character is encountered then the data adjacent to that cell in the
same row will be copied and pasted into a different sheet.

The program I have currently successfully copies A1 into Sheet 1 but not the other ones, I'm assuming there is some  kind of incrementation error, but I can't detect it.

Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub autofill_DSR()

' Variable Declarations:
'   We want variables which keep a count of the total number of rows,
' the item code character values associated, a count of the total
' number of "x" characters encountered, and a flag to signify
' sheet transfer activation


    Dim sheet_flip_flag, x_count, n As Integer
    Dim item_a, item_b As String

    Process_Control_NumRows = 16

    Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Select
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Range("D1").Select

        For n = 0 To n = (Process_Control_NumRows - 1)

            If (ActiveCell.Offset(n, 0) = "x" Or ActiveCell.Offset(n, 0) = "X") Then

                item_a = ActiveCell.Offset(n, -3).Value
                item_b = ActiveCell.Offset(n, -2).Value

                Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
                Range("A1").Select
                ActiveCell.Offset(n, 0).Value = (item_a & item_b)

                Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
                Range("D1").Select

            End If

            ActiveCell.Offset(n, 1).Value = NN

        Next n

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the code of the `For` loop in your code to read

```
For n = 0 To (Process_Control_NumRows - 1)
```

This will increment n as you want it to.